# jQuery eq function unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a bug in a program I had written, but the behavior of the error is inexplicable to me:

If I have:

```
<input type="text" name="cust_id" value="666" />
<input type="text" name="phone[]" value="666" />
```

And then use this selector:

```
var test = $("input[name=phone[]]:eq(0)");
test.css("color", "red");
```

I see this:

[image]

What I'm surprised by is the fact that the `eq(0)` selects the first input even though I explicitly tell it to find only ones with `name=phone[]`

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1xdnv1t8/

Is this expected behavior? Does the eq selector ignore attribute selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
var test = $("input[name='phone[]']:eq(0)");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/1xdnv1t8/1/)

In the [selector especification](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) states

> jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )
>
> *attribute*: An attribute name.
>
> *value*: An attribute value. **Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.**

Comment: Linking to the selector docs and explaining what you changed could be useful.

Comment: Remember to take a moment and *explain why your answer solves the problem.*

Comment: ah, the quotes are required?

Comment: Testing your selector `var test = $("input[name=phone[]]");` shows it doesn't work. See [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32054653/5195629) for why.

Comment: @dgig: Yes, they're required if the attribute value you're testing doesn't fit the definition of a [CSS *identifier*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). (The jQuery docs fudge that a bit, better to go to the spec. :-) ) If it fits the definition of an identifier the quotes are optional.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, very helpful. As you were first, you get the checkmark.

Answer (score 5):

You need to quote name attribute:

```
var test = $("input[name='phone[]']:eq(0)");
```

because `phone[]` is not valid name without quotes. So jQuery parser (or DOM) simply ignores everything invalid and treats selector as if it was simply `input[name='phone']:eq(0)`. Also worth noting, that looks like this behaviour is fixed in more up to date versions of jQuery. You use pretty old 1.6.4 in your demo, but if you check it with `1.8.x` and above it will work properly throwing error.

For example, if you try

```js
try {
  document.querySelector("input[name=phone[]]")
}
catch(e) {
  alert(e.message)
}
```

it will even throw an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[name=phone[]]' is not a valid selector.

But jQuery is more forgiving and it just selects whatever it can.

Comment: Based on what happens I think the parser ignores the invalid selector instead of treating it as `name='phone'`. Otherwise I don't see why the first `input` element would be selected: `input:eq(0)` or `input[name]`, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing quotes around the attribute value. Try this -

`var test = $('input[name="phone[]"]:eq(0)');`

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets in your selector confuse the attribute selection part as it is not quoted. Notice if you change the name of the second input to `phone` then it [works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/1xdnv1t8/2/):

```
$("input[name=phone]:eq(0)")
```

Alternatively, wrap the attribute selector in quotes:

```
$("input[name='phone']:eq(0)")
```

Answer (score 1):

While quoting the name attribute's value isn't strictly required (jQuery for the most part will work fine without them), as you noticed you can run into unusual situations when there are non-alphanumeric characters involved and jQuery interprets them as CSS notation.

The solution is to always properly escape any of these characters (`:`, `.`, `[`, `]`, etc.) as jQuery recommends, with two backslashes:

> In order to tell jQuery to treat these characters literally rather
>   than as CSS notation, they must be "escaped" by placing two
>   backslashes in front of them.

So according to the jQuery documentation, you should be using `var test = $("input[name='phone\\[\\]']:eq(0)");` as the selector (although simply properly quoting the string in your case will also work fine).

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1xdnv1t8/3/)**

Ref: [How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)

Comment: Thanks for the list of special characters to watch out for, very helpful.